# Rails link to with a font awesome icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I have a logo image that I have added a `link_to` path and also a font awesome icon to it. I also added the `onmouseover`, `onmouseout` attributes in order to change the color of the logo on `hover:`

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
<%= image_tag("logo_1.png", onmouseover: "this.src='#{asset_path('logo.png')}'", onmouseout: "this.src='#{asset_path('logo_1.png')}'") %>
<i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt" style="font-size: 20px; vertical-align: middle;"></i>
<% end %>
```

Everything works just fine, except when I hover on top of the logo image it does not grab the font awesome as well.. ti works as two separate `link_to` paths, one is the logo image and the other is the font awesome icon. How can I make it one `link_to`??

Comment: Have you considered using css to change the color of the fa icon rather than using the 2 images? The link_to will render as an anchor tag in html which you could target with a:hover {color: #...}

Comment: It might be helpful to see an image or mock-up of what you want this to look like. Do you want to fa icon to appear on hover or to display all the time?

Comment: I want both the fa icon and the logo image to display all the time... and on hover I want the fa-icon to change color and the image logo to change to another image(logo_1.png) which I've  already changed the color.

Comment: Is only happen when you hover on top of the logo? For example at the middle of the logo is working like one `link_to` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nick D, when I hover at the middle of the logo it still works like two separate `link_to`.

Comment: I just tried your code and it works fine. When i hover on the logo, the image is changing (logo to logo_1 ) and also the awesome icon changes color at the same time (more darker from the default icon color when we hover). 
First advice , try it with another awesome icon(with no css changes).
Also try to inspect your 'button' `link_to root_path` and see if the `<a href="/">` is acting like one 'image'.